# Why there is no absolute value while solving differential equations which results lnx?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

In the solutions of many mathematical problems requiring differential equation solving, I came across to the absence of absolute value with $\ln(x)$.

I can explain better with an example.

Let's consider the question below.

[image: Question]

Its answer to part (b) is also below.

[image]

In the first **A1** mark, why there is no absolute value resulting the integration of $-\tan{x}$?

We saw this behaviour on many other occasions.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find an  integrating factor not all integrating factors.

Integrating factors are facilitators and we just need one of them to solve our problem.